# Reopen and edit or ask new question for bad question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This [std::queue destructor is slow as hell, bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054496/stdqueue-destructor-is-slow-as-hell-bug) seems so interesting but the OP did not provides enough information for reproducing the problem.

I reproduced it by chance and I added this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056520/4523099. However, I am not 100% sure that the conditions I used to reproduce are the same of the OP.

Should I edit the question and ask to re-open it or should I ask a new question that contain enough information?

Comment: *I am not 100% sure that the conditions I used to reproduce are the same of the OP* - If all you need is some clarification, then drop a comment  in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the OP didn't provide enough information to reproduce the problem then the question should be closed, for exactly the reason that it *is* closed.  You're more than welcome to add a comment to help the OP understand more specifically what the problem(s) with the question are, beyond just the information in the close reason.

When the question is missing key information you shouldn't be answering the question at all.  It ends up being confusing for everyone, harmful to the OP, harmful to you if/when he clarifies the question in such a way that it's clear you were guessing wrong, and can be very confusing to future readers as well.

Wait for the author to clarify the question, and *then* post your answer, when the question is completely clear.

As far as editing the question, if the question doesn't contain enough information for you to understand the problem, then how could you possibly edit that information in?  There's only one situation where that would be appropriate, and that's if the OP posted that information in a comment (typically responding to a clarifying question) and didn't edit it into the question, at which point you can edit it in for them if you want.